# PHP Calculating next event date

Tags: php, events, datetime, date, date-arithmetic

I have a database that holds events in the following format:

**Schedules**

```
id  
show_id
starttime - datetime
endtime - datetime
repeatuntil - datetime
repeat - int
nthdayofmonth - int
repeatmultiple - int
```

show_id holds the ID number for the show which is stored.

Shows can be stored multiple times for different recurring, or different days/time variations.

startime, endtime, and repeatuntil are bit obvious as to what they do.

repeat is the type of repeat :

```
1 - hourly
2 - daily
3 - weekly
4 - monthly
5 - yearly
```

nthdayofmonth am not 100% whether this is needed or will be used
repeatmultiple is to be used when the events are wanted to be repeated every other week or every other month so on...

---

What I have been struggling with is the code that calculates when the next event occurs, I have tried various solutions from the internet and stackoverflow but am still struggling. Majority of the time my code ends up in an infinite loop and is unable to work out the correct date for the next event.

If someone is able to help out with the coding of a function that can loop through finding the next time an event occurs I will much appreciate there assistances as I am getting very frustrated and not much further from when I started.

Comment: I don't think you really want a loop for this. Have you tried creating a date object with the known occurrence, then using date_add() to get to the next?

Comment: @Rob Allen but that would only work for the first time the event is repeated?

Comment: you are correct. When you run that, you will get the very next event and only the very next event. But that function can be the cornerstone of what ever other processes you need. A refactoring could give you the N'th instance or N number of dates. Eventually you could plug it into a loop to build out a calendar or other collection of event dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can approach this by characterizing the two functionalities that you really need here.

First, you need a method of calculating the next DateTime that a *given* `Show` will execute. This is irrespective of any other `Show`, and has nothing to do with what will come first. You need a method that, given the `starttime, endtime, etc` criteria, will calculate the next time that this `Show` will execute.

Once you are able to determine when any given `Show` will execute, you can move on to determining *which* `Show` will execute next. You could loop through the database, calculating Next times and storing the soonest...or even serialize the Next DateTime for each `Show`, and query the database for the smallest.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't helped me solve my problem mentioned in my question.